# Как сделать работоспособным присваивание main?

Tags: c

Хочу скомпилировать такой код:

```
void function () {
  puts("Hello world");
}

main = function;
```

Местами он [компилируется](http://ideone.com/7FYd0G), но при выполнении падает с ошибкой, местами [не компилируется](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jT3k1Ytei1F8MV3h):

> ```
> prog.c:5:1: error: initializer element is not computable at load time
>  main = function;
>  ^
> ```

Как сделать, чтобы такое скомпилировалась, запустилась и не упало хоть где-нибудь?

---

http://ideone.com/BZMp2V - изменение `void` на `int` и добавление `return 0` не помогает:

```
int function () {
  puts("Hello world");
  return 0;
}

main = function;
```

На ideone программы [32-битные](http://ideone.com/SBIM7d), так что с кастом указателя в неявный int тоже не связано.

Comment: Осталось попробовать присвоить `for = while;`... :) Кстати, скомпилировать-то можно, если объявить `main` как указатель на функцию. VC даже не ругается на отсутствие точки входа. Но падает...

Comment: @Harry, я точно видел где-то работоспособный код с `main=`.

Comment: Лишь бы минус поставить. Неужели не интересно?((

Comment: gcc компилирует. с warnings, но лопает :)

Comment: @Harry, кстати, по второй ссылке предупреждение: `prog.c:5:1: warning: 'main' is usually a function [-Wmain]` - обращаю внимание на слово _usually_ - т. е. обычно, но не всегда.

Comment: @PinkTux а результат компиляции работает?

Comment: @PinkTux, но оно завершается с ошибкой. `int` и `return 0` пробовал - не помогло.

Comment: Надо просто объектник посмотреть. Или ассемблерный листинг. Возможно, линкер видит `main` и пытается сделать вызов по адресу символа, но, поскольку он указывает не на вход в функцию, а на переменную...

Comment: @PinkTux VC++ просто делает `main` указателем в сегменте данных... со всеми вытекающими, так как считает это точкой входа.

Comment: Вспомнил только [такую](http://jroweboy.github.io/c/asm/2015/01/26/when-is-main-not-a-function.html) статью, но там все же хотя бы тип `main` указывается... [её перевод](https://tproger.ru/translations/main-is-usually-a-function-so-then-when-is-it-not/)

Comment: Да, интересно было бы записать в `main` просто код джампа на `f()`. Блин, мне как раз прямо сейчас убегать нужно! Если за пару часов никто не сделает - приду, поиграюсь...

Comment: `void *main = function;` в Ubuntu собирается, но (!!!) мы видим в nm a.out `0000000000601038 D main` (адрес в сегменте данных (и даже поместив туда jmp function все равно получим segfault, поскольку эта память закрыта для исполнения))

Comment: @avp, а скормить какой-нибудь флаг компилятору, чтобы он всё память сделал rwe?

Comment: @Qwertiy, может тогда лучше флаг компилятору, который меняет точку входа?

Comment: Ловите в ответе `--entry=function`

Comment: @Grundy, кажется, твой вариант реализовали))

Comment: @Harry, ну что?

Comment: @Qwertiy Фокус не удался. Я не настолько хорошо знаю ассемблер для Windows, так что по моим представлениям - код там лежит верный... Но дальше - или туда не осуществляется переход (`call _main`) не проходит, или выполнение кода в сегменте данных просто не разрешено, но как тут крутиться - не знаю. Вернее, немного догадываюсь, но это уже требует серьезной работы и изучения, и в любом случае просто в рамках C не решится...

Answer (score 5):

Задание выполнено, сэр!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func () {
  puts("xa-xa-xa");
  exit(0);
}

void *main = func;

avp@wubu:hashcode$ gcc t.c --entry=func && ./a.out 
xa-xa-xa
avp@wubu:hashcode$
```

Правда, пришлось добавить `exit()`.

Без exit валится. 
Если посмотреть в gdb,

```
(gdb) layout asm
```

то `func()` завершается вот так

```
0x400535 <func+15>              pop    %rbp                                │
0x400536 <func+16>              retq                                       │
```

Смотрим стек

```
(gdb) si
(gdb) p $sp
$3 = (void *) 0x7fffffffde70
(gdb) p *(0x7fffffffde70)
$5 = 1
(gdb)
```

и видим тут лежит 1, а не нормальный адрес возврата

Comment: `--entry=func` - а это случайно не точку входа подменяет?

Comment: А зачем exit? выполнения разве само не прекратится? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, но с мусорным кодом в `eax`. А exit делает красивый нолик. UPDATE: Хм.. `eax` или `ax`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, а `return` какой-нибудь не делает то же самое? И почему с main не надо добавлять exit?

Comment: @Grundy, в конце main надо `return 0;`. Точнее, в плюсах не надо - там компилятор его сам добавит. Но в си без плюсов надо. А здесь си. `int func() { ... return 0; }` скорее всего сработает.

Comment: @Qwertiy [надо два нуля](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=33790123#33790123).

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, --entry подменяет точку входа. Интересно, есть ли система, в которой можно задать "indirect" точку входа? Тогда call по `*main` был бы совсем то, что хочется.

Comment: @Grundy, а вот без `exit` получаем segfault при возврате (почему?  не знаю).

Comment: @Qwertiy, если интересно, я там еще немного стек посмотрел...

Comment: VC++ - компилируется с предупреждением, ничего не выводит, валится...

Comment: @Harry, а кто обещал, что в M$ что-то будет?

Comment: @avp Это информация, а не наезд :)

Comment: @Harry информационный наезд.

Answer (score 1):

На каждую проблему найдётся свой `#define`:

```
void function () {
    puts("Hello world");
}

#define main static main
#define function 0

main = function;
```

---

```
int main() {
    function();
}
```

[Проверка выполнения.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/6DPkuiekqHuOPT1b)

Comment: ну не :-) это не спортивно :)

Comment: @Grundy не вижу метки [tag:без-define] :)

Answer (score 0):

Другой вариант: [использовать вложенные функции](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HfuQlkO4vCCgQgtt) ([расширение gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html)):

```
void f() {
    void (*main)();

    void function () {
        puts("Hello world");
    }

    main = function;

    main();
}

int main() {
    f();
}
```